# Prioritizing packets streaming in OpenFlow, mininet

Tags: streaming, mininet, openflow

I am doing work on security and priority in SDN.
I have a typology of this form

```
h1---s1--s2---h2
```

I have to pass packets of h1 to h2, prioritizing packets streaming. And check somehow they are correct.  i don't know how to do that with OpenFlow and MiniNet. Anyone have any idea how to do it?

Comment: Can you explain on what basis you want to prioritize? Are you talking about QoS?

Comment: If it is a multimedia package , pass from h1 to h2 and if another file is spooled.

Answer (score 0):

I believe from security and priority, you mean to say [FireWall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) and [Traffic shaping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_shaping) services respectively. As far as I know you cannot achieve traffic shaping just be OpenFlow(Though firewall service could be achieved to an extent by OpenFlow). In short OpenFlow is meant for setting forwarding rules for an in coming packet. Though there are plugins such as NICIRA which can add some functionality such as handling TCP, UDP, ARP packets, but the primary job of openflow packet is to forward packet to next port, drop or punt to controller based on flow rules.

However in your case, You need to implement [SFC](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Service_Function_Chaining:Main). You need to deploy firewall or traffic shaping applications(an opensource traffic shaping application [here](http://wiki.opentrafficshaper.org/)) in a separate server. you need to configure VXLAN on S1 and S2. Then add flows on S1 and S2 such that packets are forwarded to the server. and other flow to forward the flows from the server to next destination. In the Server you apply firewall and traffic shaping rules on packet by packet basis.

Hope this basic information atleast helps you to where to look for information / get going.

---

**EDIT**

Please look at really good tutorial from [David Mahler](https://www.youtube.com/user/mahler711), specifically the introduction to [OpenFlow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l25Ukkmk6Sk), this would clear your doubts on Packet traversal in OpenvSwitch. 
 Coming to Controller, there are number of controller implementations with languages from C++, Python, Java to Ruby.

Assuming you are a python developer, you can check with [POX](http://httphttps://github.com/noxrepo/pox://), here are good tutorial links([link1](http://sdnhub.org/tutorials/pox/) and [link2](https://github.com/mininet/openflow-tutorial/wiki/Create-a-Learning-Switch)) however I'm not sure how well its maintained, I see the commits for code was last done 3 years ago, not sure it is actively maintained. There is also example to parse the packet [here](http://archive.openflow.org/wk/index.php/OpenFlow_Tutorial#ofp_packet_out_OpenFlow_message), where you can apply appropriate algorithm.  If you are looking for Java there are controllers such as Floodlight and Opendaylight, which has pretty much better community support.

Comment: there any way to put a rule in OpenFlow to call a Python program? and then forward the packet if it meets the algorithm?

Comment: Nope, this is generally done at controller end, you send the packet to controller, apply the algorithm/business rule and send back the packet/modified packet.

Comment: Sorry for the insistence.... in s1 i have to add a rule that sends the packet to the controller, the controller applies the algorithm and forwards it to s2 if it meets. I use mininet  to simulate the network. How can i introduce the algorithm in the controller?

I'm sorry but I don't have idea about this and is very importat for my project. 

Thank you very very much.

Comment: @MariaGomezCliment updated answer, there are good documents for floodlight and ODL, however due to large scale development, both has(certainly ODL) has become bit complicated, is bit tricky to learn as well, however once you learn it should be much faster to to implement.

Comment: @MariaGomezCliment missed to add Ryu, Ryu is developed using python and has active community support